# How to Acoustically Treat kitchen-extension of room?

Tags: acoustics, room-treatment

I have a room layout like this. The red panels are acoustic panels placed around the room, and the squiggly surface is gonna be a curtain. There's an extension at the upper part of the room that used to be a small kitchen area, which I don't know how to acoustically treat.
[image: room design]

Now the actual part of the kitchen looks like this
[image: Actual part of room]

There's an entire countertop and several fixtures around. How would someone go about acoustically treating this without having to remove the fixtures?

I have a lot of 1 inch flat foam lying around:
[image: flat foam]

And I was wondering if I could use this and place it above the cabinets / countertop, and maybe wrap some cloth around it to make it look nice.

Thank you!

Comment: This foam, is good for just about nothing when it comes to treating a room... Question is, why do you want to treat that space? why do you believe it creates a problem, if there's a problem that this space creates, what's that? What kind of space you're trying to create? Mastering space? listening? mixing? What kind of speakers you have and what are the dimensions and ceiling level of the space? Are the speakers the purple ones in the image? how far away do you sit? how far away from each other are they?

Comment: What do you mean by "treat"? Shape the sound within the room or isolate it from other rooms? Putting soft & squishy stuff on the walls & hard surfaces will reduce internal reflections, mainly in the upper frequencies - which might make it sound 'nicer' for watching TV or playing the HiFI, but it won't do anything real towards frequency shaping & nothing at all towards isolation. Having that smaller room jutting out from the main space is also going to play uncontrolled havoc with the bass frequencies as you move round the space.

Comment: @frcake I'm planning to use the space mostly for band practice and recording space. So by "treat", I meant fixing the overall reverb and acoustics of the room. With what I have right now, the kitchen space there is causing some amount of reverb even when I'm standing in the main part of the room, because the rest of the room has been set up with acoustic panels.The purple ones are the speakers, but the positioning is not yet final.

Comment: @edrichchans your best bet is a very thick very heavy curtain, now the bass in there is another story..  the foam you show as Tetsujin stated will only affect the upper frequencies, meaning the RT will remain in the mids to low and create mud. Curtains can also create mud/boom for the same reason but in lower frequencies. If you cant put a 2-leaf wall there and actually separate the space, first thing i'd try is to move things around until it's not that of a problem or rehearse in lower volume, or rehearse with headphones...

Comment: @edrichhans can you suspend things off of the ceiling?

Comment: @frcake thanks for your help! Unfortunately suspending things off the ceiling is out of the question right now. Maybe blocking off the entire room with heavy curtain is my best bet right now